# Could not find a storyboard named 'Storyboard.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle

Tags: ios, storyboard, nsbundle

I created a new target in an iOS project and added some of my files as well as a new storyboard file. But when running in the simulator (I haven't tried the device) it pukes at `UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([PKPreprocessAppDelegate class]))` in main.c:

```
(lldb) po $eax 

(unsigned int) $1 = 151596752 Could not find a storyboard named 'Storyboard.storyboard' 
in bundle NSBundle </Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/007281D7-F09F-482A-A57A-CEEC1C65176B/XXXXX Preprocess.app> (loaded)
```

The plist has a matching Storyboard.storyboard under the key `UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone`. I also checked that the `Copy Bundle Resources` has that storyfile listed. Within the bundle the file is at directory `en.lproj` (though named as `Storyboard.storyboardc`). I even tried copying out of the `en.lproj` directory to no avail.

EDIT:
I also tried plist under key `UIMainStoryboardFile` still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you click on your projects -> TARGETS -> iPhone/iPod deployment info, and check to see your storyboard is listed there? Also, Click on your storyboard file -> Show the file inspector -> target membership, make sure there is a check mark on the project.

Comment: Yes the storyboard is listed and yes the checkmark is on the target I intended.

Comment: Oh wait, you're right about the deployment info, it's spelled wrong. I'm running into another error when I fixed that. Let me double check.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch! Post so I can give you the credit. Also if you know why I have to set both the plist and that deployment info, you can explain it to me, too. Why are there two separate places that seems to me one would suffice. :/

Comment: Glad it helped. Not sure why we need to set both the plist and the deployment info though. I just make sure those are set correctly each time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comment section:

Can you click on your projects -> TARGETS -> iPhone/iPod deployment info, and check to see your storyboard is listed there? Also, Click on your storyboard file -> Show the file inspector -> target membership, make sure there is a check mark on the project.

Comment: great man, u made my day, i need to check my project previously tests was checked in target membership....